# Is this reverse interpolation?

Tags: transformation, data-analysis

I have a large number (say 3000) of sensor data taken at equally spaced time intervals (concretely the reflectivity of a sensor passing over an EAN13 barcode).

I want to transform this vector (array) of length 3000 to an array of length 95 containing the numbers 1 or 0 (representing the 95 black and white lines in the barcode).

If the number of data was a multiple of 95 such as 950, I would average the first 10 data points and map the result to either 1 or 0 depending on a cut off. Then I'd do the same with points 11 to 20 etc.

How would I go about doing this for a number that is not a multiple of 95?

Naively I would average over 3000/95=31.5 data points, i.e., I would take 31 points and the 32nd with half weight.

Is this a good idea?
Are there better ways?
Does such transformation have a name?

Comment: Well, your scanner probably take some margins to the left and and right to ensure that all of your barcode is captured, or are you sure that the barcode starts exactly at $0$ and finish exactly at $3000$ ? I guess that you have to detect the end markers and discard unneeded data first. Also keep in mind that the angle of the line crossing your code will vary (do not assume perpendicular cross), so you will never have a perfect division anyway. Averaging seems good considering that.

Comment: It is a handmade (lego) scanner. The margins are easily cut. So, yes the data starts and ends at a black line and there are no margins left.

Comment: The threshold is there to help, don't really need weighting I think. Just consider that data $i$ contribute to bar number $\operatorname{floor}(\dfrac{95\times i}{nbpoints})$ rather than using a floating point step.